# Does tod_training in object_recognition require fiducial markers on training images?

Tags: ros, tod-detecting, object-recognition, tod-training

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been following the [Training Base Creation tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tod_training/Tutorials/BaseCreation) to create a database for recognizing objects using packages *tod_training* and *tod_detecting* in stack *object_recognition*. I noted that the supplied images for training (snapshots from different angles) all show fiducial markers.

Ultimately, I want to train the data base using data supplied by our University lab that has been collected without fiducial markers.

Is there a possibility to use tod_training *without* fiducial markers?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9321/does-tod_training-in-object_recognition-require-fiducial-markers-on-training-images?/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-03-07

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-03-23**:
Hey dlmypr make sure to also check out http://answers.ros.org/question/505/purpose-of-pose-estimations-in-tod_detecting and http://answers.ros.org/question/504/physical-setup-for-collecting-tod_training-data too. I think Alexander Shishkov has done a pretty awesome job on answering questions on tod_* today. If you're doing the training process please share your experience.

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-03-13**:
I have my own bag files with point clouds and 2d image data. I need to collect some ideas on how to work around this obstacle this week, but haven't done anything in this direction yet. I will let you know if I come up with something, and would be happy if you did so, too.

**Comment by [dlmypr](https://answers.ros.org/users/128/dlmypr/) on 2011-03-11**:
Did you every tried to make a training base with you own bag files? And did you succeeded? If yes I need your help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it is impossible now. But you can modify tod_training (turn off finding fiducial markers and detection of transformation between current image and the some abstract coordinate system) :-)
In tod_training we require fiducial marker(or markers) for detection transformation between different frames in bag file.  For each frame we calculate transformation between the camera coordinate system and the some abstract coordinate system (where coordinates of chessboard corners are the same as in fiducial.yaml). Calculated pose is saved to Features3d->Camera->Pose. Using this information we can merge point clouds from different images to the one for example.

You can use other fiducial markers (one or some chessboards or grids of circles). Parameters of your fiducial marker/markers should be in fiducial.yaml file. tod_training package contains tool for generating this file.

---

Originally posted by [Alexander Shishkov](https://answers.ros.org/users/334/alexander-shishkov/) with karma: 191 on 2011-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-03-25**:
I like the high-level info about the fiducial markers on rev 17. But doesn't switching off the transformation leave us without pose information that is required later in tod_detecting when trying to recognize objects?

**Comment by [Alexander Shishkov](https://answers.ros.org/users/334/alexander-shishkov/) on 2011-03-24**:
I don't know. Ethan supports this wiki page.  I like more the earlier version.

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-03-24**:
Why is the current wiki less elaborate?

**Comment by [Alexander Shishkov](https://answers.ros.org/users/334/alexander-shishkov/) on 2011-03-23**:
Also I recommend you to learn old version of tutorial (for example http://www.ros.org/wiki/tod_training/Tutorials/BaseCreation?action=recall&rev=17). They contain some useful information about fiducial markers and poses.